# latex: printing a variable in roman numerals

Tags: latex, roman-numerals

I'm typesetting in LaTeX, and I'd like to display a "variable" (in my case, a reference \ref{blah} to an item number in list) in roman rather than the default arabic.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3):

You can try `\def\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}` inside an `enumerate` environment -- this changes both labels and refs,  but you'll have to then explicitly undo it (if you want to).

Answer (score 2):

lowercase

`\romannumeral 0\ref{blah}\relax`

uppercase

`\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral 0\ref{blah}}`

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this.  I tried the first suggestion, however, and it didn't seem to work:  the output is still arabic.

Comment: Perhaps I can troubleshoot better if I know what the various bits of the expression are doing.  What are the "0" and the "\relax" for?

Comment: `0` is needed because of if `\ref{blah}` is `??` then `\romannumeral` gives an error and `\romannumeral 0??` gives `??`. `\relax` is needed because of if there are digits after `\ref{blah}` you have a wrong result. For example, if `\ref{blah}` is `1` then `\romannumeral 0\ref{blah}0` gives `x` rather than `i`. And `\romannumeral 0\ref{blah}\relax 0` gives `x0` as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

What are the references *to*? Usually, you would redefine how that particular counter is displayed.

For example, to change how a section number is displayed, you could use the following command:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

Now, each command that internally uses `\thesection` will print the section number as a roman numeral.

Similar commands work for `chapter`, `figure` etc.

`\roman` (lowercase `r`) yield lowercase roman numerals.

Comment: The references are to an item number in a list.  I've made the item numbers output in roman using \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}, but this doesn't seem to carry over to references.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @anon: Oops, I didn’t notice the part about list items.

Answer (score 1):

For lowercase: `{\romannumeral \ref{blah}}`

For uppercase: `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral \ref{blah}}`

Answer (score 0):

A good solution seems to me to declare

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
```

in the header and then cite by `\eqref{blah}` to get your (iii) for the third item. (Note that `\eqref` requires the [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Alternatively, write `(\ref{blah})`.)

Comment: Your use of `\eqref` requires the inclusion of [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), I guess?.

Comment: True. I'll amend my post.